# How do I enable Trash service?

Tags: directory, trash

Suddenly I am unable to empty trash and get this message:

```
Could not empty trash
This features requires a trash service to be present (such as the one supplied by Thunar)
```

I get a similar error when I try to open images or other files within a folder. How do I fix it?

I am running Ubuntu Studio 22.10 with XFce

Comment: What file-system is involved?   You can have *trash* enabled on a system (for the main file-system), but it's not available on other mounted file-systems as there is no capacity for deleted files to be kept on the volume.  Ubuntu Studio is also KDE for 22.10, so is your system a new install, as complications can occur if you *release-upgraded* a Ubuntu Studio Xfce system as outlined in Ubuntu Studio documentation.

Comment: It's running the standard Linux and Ubuntu file system, not FAT32 or one of the others.

Comment: Please be specific; Ubuntu supports many *fs* options, with the defaults available varying on installation media used which you've not specified. You've highlighted already you're not using a default system as 22.10 uses KDE Plasma (not Xfce).

Comment: Oops! Apparently I was mistaken as this system IS running FAT32 with EFI. No matter, the point is, nothing has changed on my system other than some updates in the last couple days and now I get file system errors. I also just discovered that neither Netflix nor YouTube will play in Firefox even though DRM is enabled and codecs are installed. Whatever the default, the desktop in use is Xfce. This is not a new installation and again, all was working before the updates in the last couple days.

Comment: Apparently I am also unable to open any files whether in a folder or not IF they are on the desktop. From the File Manager, they open properly.

Comment: I finally got the file system and videos working but with no audio on the latter. Settings appear correct but no sound. To get this far, I removed and reinstalled xfce4. Audio is HDMI. Also, dual monitors revert to mirroring rather than extending after reboot.